# Moving an object from one region to another in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently I have a map in the format topojson, I would like an object to move from point A to point B. on this map there are departments and municipalities. For now  between two departaments, I just want to move an element, it can be a circle for example from point A to point B generating a transition.

[image]

[image]

In the attached image the structure and an example of what I want to achieve. For example I want from "ANTIOQUIA" an element to move until "BOYACA". It would be great if I could go from the centroid of department to the centroid of department B. How can I achieve this?

```
    var width = 900,
        height = 900;

    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
      .attr("class", "tooltip")             
      .style("opacity", 0);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.json("https://cdn.rawgit.com/finiterank/mapa-colombia-js/9ae3e4e6/colombia-municipios.json", function(error, co) {
      console.log(co)
      var subunits = topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios);
      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale(2000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
        .center([-61,43])
        .rotate([2,3,2]);

      var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);




    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .translate([0, 0])
        .scale(1)
        .scaleExtent([1, 8])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);


    var g = svg.append("g");

    svg
        .call(zoom) // delete this line to disable free zooming
        .call(zoom.event);

      g.append("path")
        .datum(subunits)
        .attr("d", path);

    function zoomed() {
        console.log("zoom")
      g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
      g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }

     //departments
      g.selectAll(".dpto")
        .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.depts).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "depts " + "_" + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path)



     //municipalities
      g.selectAll(".mpio")
        .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .on('mouseover', mouseoverMun )
        .on('mouseout',mouseoutMun)
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "mpio " + "_" + d.id + " " + d.properties.dpt})
        .attr("d", path)
    })

    function mouseoverMun(d){
      // Turn the department blue
      d3.selectAll("."+d.properties.dpt)
         .style("fill","steelblue")

      // Turn the municipality orange
      //d3.select(this).style("fill","orange");

      // Show a tooltip  
      div.style("opacity", .9)  
         .html(d.properties.name)   
         .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")        
         .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
         document.getElementById("department").innerHTML=d.properties.dpt

    }

    function mouseoutMun() {
      d3.selectAll(".mpio").style("fill","none");
      div.style("opacity",0);
      document.getElementById("department").innerHTML='';

    }
```

This is what I am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/0yLfzowy/

Comment: Just an explanation: you don't want to move the *object*, you want to move an *element*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes! I will update the topic..

Comment: @GerardoFurtado This is what I am trying to do.
Http://www.carto.net/svg/samples/path_animation.svg

Comment: Yes, I know. Btw, congrats for the freehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get those centroids.

In this solution, I have an `centroids` object, which is populating when you actually draw the paths:

```
var centroids = {};

g.selectAll(".dpto")
    //etc
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        if (d.properties.dpt === "ANTIOQUIA" || d.properties.dpt === "BOYACA") {
            centroids[d.properties.dpt] = path.centroid(d)
        }
        return path(d);
    });
```

Then, it's just a matter of appending the element (here, a circle) and moving it:

```
var circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("cx", centroids.ANTIOQUIA[0])
    .attr("cy", centroids.ANTIOQUIA[1]);

circle.transition()
    .delay(1000)
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("cx", centroids.BOYACA[0])
    .attr("cy", centroids.BOYACA[1]);
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzfs55bg/

Comment: Excellent! You make it look very easy! I'm really amazed !. Just a little detail taking advantage of your great knowledge, I'm trying to give a 3d effect. I want it to start when the circle starts small and becomes bigger and finally becomes small until it disappears. As well as in this example. http://www.carto.net/svg/samples/path_animation.svg I would like too that the curved line also appears. If you want I do it in a separate question Thank you so much, you're a master.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642330/achieve-transition-effect-of-an-element-in-d3-js