# Achieve transition effect of an element using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm moving an element from one point to another. But specifically I want to achieve this animation:

http://carto.net/svg/samples/path_animation.svg

My knowledge in d3.js are somewhat limited, I do not know how to generate this curve line and I also do not know how to do 3d perspective, in which the circle should appear, then be very small and grow and eventually become small until disappearing, as well As in the attached link. How can I do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/bzfs55bg/

```
      var circle = svg.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr("cx", centroids.ANTIOQUIA[0])
        .attr("cy", centroids.ANTIOQUIA[1]);

      circle.transition()
        .delay(1000)
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("cx", centroids.BOYACA[0])
        .attr("cy", centroids.BOYACA[1]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer contain 3 main steps:

First, we have to create a path from point A to point B, simulating an arc. There are several ways to do that, and your question is not clear. Here, I'm using a quadratic curve:

```
var arc = svg.append("path")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "yellow")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("d", "M" + centroids.ANTIOQUIA[0] + "," +
        centroids.ANTIOQUIA[1] + " Q" + centroids.BOYACA[0] +
        "," + centroids.ANTIOQUIA[1] + " " +
        centroids.BOYACA[0] + "," + centroids.BOYACA[1]);
```

This path can have a colour or be transparent, it doesn't matter.

Second, we use Bostock's famous [translate along path](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868) code to translate the element along that arc. I changed the function to pass the element along with the path, so we can change its size:

```
circle.transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(arc.node(), circle.node()));
    //the second argument is the circle -----------------^

function translateAlong(path, circle) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    return function(d, i, a) {
        return function(t) {
            d3.select(circle).attr("r", circleSize(t))
            //here we can change circle's size
            var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
            return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
        };
    };
}
```

Finally, I'm using a linear scale to make the circle big and small again:

```
var circleSize = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
    .range([4, 10, 4]);
```

The domain here goes from 0 to 1 because this is the range of values the parameter `t` can assume.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zkc2wton/

Here is a second fiddle, changing the opacity at the beginning and at the end of the movement: http://jsfiddle.net/4pdusase/

Comment: hey, can you help me with that please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651584/put-a-real-coordinate-on-a-map-in-d3-js

Answer (score 0):

How to draw a curve line between points:

```
                     //draw a line  
                    var curveData = [{ x: centroids.ANTIOQUIA[0], y: centroids.ANTIOQUIA[1] }, { x: centroids.BOYACA[0], y: centroids.BOYACA[0] }];
                    //make a line function
                    var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                          .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                          .interpolate("monotone");//change it as per your choice.

//make a path       
var myPath = d3.select('svg').append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFunction(curveData))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("fill", "none");
```

Please refer interpolation for the curves you may like [here](http://ttps://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js.)

Further moving point along a line and disappearing.

```
//transition along a path
  circle.transition()
      .duration(10000)

      .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(myPath.node()))
        .style("opacity",0);//transitioning the opacity to make it vanish.                  
// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
```

3d i don't know :(

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xgnq27y1/)

Comment: I thank you for the attempt, but how can I make it to start the transparent and small circle and in the end first become small and finally disappear?

Comment: not clear you want to start small circle but when transition ends you want the circle to become small..quite ambiguous

Comment: Is not ambiguous. Watch this animation. http://carto.net/svg/samples/path_animation.svg. This effect I need to give 3d perspective. A small circle appears faded to a fixed size, and finally when it is finished, it becomes small and finally disappears, but first it becomes small and then disappears.

Comment: An example the circle has a radio, 5. when the animation starts, it starts with opacity of 0 and a size of 1 and later it becomes big and the opacity increases until reaching 1 and the size until it reaches 5. when it is finished The animation, the size will be 2 and its opacity will be 0. this is the transition I need :) such as the animation link

Comment: I think my answer can get you started...once you understand transition then  you can do that.