# Put a real coordinate on a map in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have an animation that moves a circle from the centroid of a region corresponding to one department, to another.

```
        var arc = g.append("path")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "yellow")
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("d", "M" + centroids.ANTIOQUIA[0] + "," + centroids.ANTIOQUIA[1] + " Q" + centroids.BOYACA[0] + "," + centroids.ANTIOQUIA[1] + " " + centroids.BOYACA[0] + "," + centroids.BOYACA[1]);

      var circle = g.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + centroids.ANTIOQUIA[0] + "," + centroids.ANTIOQUIA[1] + ")");

      circle.transition()
        .delay(1000)
        .duration(1000)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .transition()
        .duration(8000)
        .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(arc.node(), circle.node()))
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .style("opacity", 0);
```

I want the animation to start from the point I'm indicating in the image( more or less),
[image]

to a real coordinate drawn from google maps.

```
Colombia/@5.0653397,-75.5230936,15z/
```

[image]
But this time from the point I indicated in the image to a real coordinate. How can I do it? thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/v4x8s3tw/

Comment: Where did you get your topojson? It contains coordinates that aren't actually in Colombia, if they are latitude longitude pairs (eg: `[-57,49]`, Colombia is big, but it doesn't stretch to 49 degrees north, 57 degrees north, which is in Newfoundland, Canada.). You are treating them as lat long pairs by using a d3 projection, but as indicated they can't be. As such, the latitude longitude pair you have posted ~`[-75,5]` uses a different coordinate system than your topojson so using the same projection for each will not work. You need to know how to translate between the two coordinate systems.

Comment: Aligning features that use different coordinate systems is not possible without knowing how they differ. If you know how they differ, or use a topojson that is projected in proper latitude longitude pairs (WGS84 datum), then this question has a fairly simple resolution

Comment: @AndrewReid This topojson is not mine, I just got it off the internet. Then what should I do?

Comment: @AndrewReid if I use that, can be more easy? https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/tree/master/countries/colombia

Comment: Yes, that can be projected properly (it uses latitude longitude pairs), but it doesn't have the same subdivisions. In any event, see this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/1eyjft66/ . You need to set the origin of the arc with an svg coordinate rather than a centroid coord, and the destination coordinate with another svg coordinate (which you can get by projecting a point). To convert from a lat/long point in real life to svg use `projection([long,lat])`, this should be clearer in the fiddle. Hmm, looking at your map, I could really use a return trip to Colombia about now.

Comment: @AndrewReid Thank you very much for your dedication, I have a long way to learn about d3.js. Then I should look at the code above to have the subdivisions. But the biggest problem is that my previous map zoomed. If I zoom, the points will move or stop being precise ?. An example is this coordinate . Look at the zoom level for example. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://www.google.com.co/maps/place/Tarapaca,+Tarapac%C3%A1,+Amazonas/@-2.8913064,-69.7432617,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13 ! 1m7! 3m6! 1s0x8e15a43aae1594a3: 0x9a0d9a04eff2a340! 2sColombia! 3b1! 8m2! 3d4.570868! 4d-74.297333! 3m4! 1s0x91f054ba12ec2e71: 0x32d4d25a86e8238f! 8m2! 3d-2.8912664! 4d-69.7412109